# Pre-fetch data using vuex and vue-resource

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource, vuex

I'm building an app following this structure: http://vuex.vuejs.org/en/structure.html

My `components/App.vue` like this:

```
<template>
<div id="app">
  <course :courses="courses"></course>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Course from './course.vue'
import { addCourses } from '../vuex/actions'

export default {
  vuex: {
    getters: {
      courses: state => state.courses,          
    },
    actions: {
      addCourses,
    }
  },

  ready() {
    this.addCourses(this.fetchCourses())
  },

  components: { Course },

  methods: {
    fetchCourses() {
      // what do I have to do here
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

How can I fetch the data and set it to the `state.courses` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just figured it out:
in `/components/App.vue` `ready` function, I just call:

```
 ready() {
    this.addCourses()
  },
```

in `vuex/actions.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

export const addCourses = ({ dispatch }) => {
  Vue.http.get('/api/v1/courses')
    .then(response => {
      let courses = response.json()

      courses.map(course => {
        course.checked = false
        return course
      })

      dispatch('ADD_COURSES', courses)
    })
}
```

and in `vuex/store.js`:

```
const mutations = {
  ADD_COURSES (state, courses) {
    state.courses = courses
  }
}
```